# Drop a column in pandas if all values equal 1?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I drop columns in pandas where all values in that column are equal to a particular number? For instance, consider this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'C': [1, 1, 1, 1]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  1
3  1  3  1
```

How would I drop the `1` columns so that the output is:

```
   B
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with test if at least one non `1` value by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.ne(1).any()]
```

Or test for `1` by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for all Trues per columns and inverted mask by `~`:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.eq(1).all()]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   B
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

EDIT:

> One consideration is what do you want to happen if you have a column with Nan and 1 only?

Then replace `NaN`s to `0` by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and use same solution like before:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.fillna(0).ne(1).any()]

df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.fillna(0).eq(1).all()]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Very helpful. Note however, that option 1 works on this simple case but also removes unwanted columns on my real data. Option 2 is spot on, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any`:

```
df.loc[:, df.ne(1).any()]
```

Answer (score 2):

One consideration is what do you want to happen if you have a column with Nan and 1 only?

If you want to drop under this condition also, you will to either fillna with 1 or add or and new condition.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'C': [1, 1, 1, np.nan]})
print(df)

   A  B    C
0  1  0  1.0
1  1  1  1.0
2  1  2  1.0
3  1  3  NaN
```

All these leave that column with NaN and 1's.

```
df.loc[:, df.ne(1).any()]
df.loc[:, ~df.eq(1).all()]
```

So, you can add this addition to drop that column also.

```
df.loc[:, ~(df.eq(1) | df.isna()).all()]
```

Output:

```
   B
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```